# Get absolute maximum value from f64 array

Tags: rust

I have an array, let's say:

```
let arr: Vec<f64> = vec![1.5, 1.1, -1.6, 0.9, -0.5];
```

I want the absolute maximum of this array:

```
let abs_max = arr."some functions";
println!("{}", abs_max); // Gives 1.6 (or -1.6, but not 1.5).
```

Is there a smart, maybe almost inline, way of doing this? Or do i have to create my own function which iterates through all the values by for loop and compares the values?

---

I've tried the following suggestion made in this post:

```
let abs_max = arr.iter().max_by(|a, b| a.abs().total_cmp(b.abs()))
```

And this code gives the following error:

```
error[E0599]: no method named `abs` found for reference `&&{float}` in the current scope
  --> src\main.rs:51:44
   |
51 |   let abs_max = arr.iter().max_by(|a, b| a.abs().total_cmp(b.abs()));
   |                                            ^^^ method not found in `&&{float}`

error[E0599]: no method named `abs` found for reference `&&{float}` in the current scope
  --> src\main.rs:51:62
   |
51 |   let abs_max = arr.iter().max_by(|a, b| a.abs().total_cmp(b.abs()));
   |                                                              ^^^ method not found in `&&{float}`
```

Answer (score 4):

In Rust, we usually operate on iterators rather than collections like vectors directly, so all of the juicy "operate on a collection" functions are going to be in [`std::iter::Iterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html).

Now, `Iterator` *has* a [`max`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.max) function, which would work for integers, but it won't work for floats, because floats are not totally ordered (`NaN`, as usual, is a problem).

If you had a collection of integers or anything else that implemented the [`Ord`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/trait.Ord.html) trait, you could write

```
arr.iter().max()
```

which would return an `Option<T>` containing the maximum value, or `None` if the collection was empty.

However, `f64` and the other floating-point types don't implement `Ord`. Fortunately, the wonderful writers of the Rust documentation for `Iterator::max` thought of this.

> Note that `f32`/`f64` doesn’t implement `Ord` due to NaN being incomparable. You can work around this by using `Iterator::reduce`:
>
> ```
> assert_eq!(
>     [2.4, f32::NAN, 1.3]
>         .into_iter()
>         .reduce(f32::max)
>         .unwrap(),
>     2.4
> );
> ```

So we can apply [`reduce`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.reduce) to [`f64::max`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.f64.html#method.max) (which is like `Ord::max` except that it works for the non-total ordering of `f64`). Adapting a bit to your use case, we get

```
arr.iter().copied().reduce(f64::max)
```

Again, this returns an `Option<f64>` which is empty if the initial collection is empty. You can `unwrap` if you know the initial collection to be nonempty. Also, if you're never using the array again after this point (i.e. you can pass ownership of it to the iterator), you can use `arr.into_iter()` rather than `arr.iter().copied()` to save yourself a copy of each element.

This compares using `f64::max`, the "usual" ordering of `f64`. But it sounds like you want a custom ordering, namely the maximum *by absolute value*. We can use [`max_by`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.max_by) to get this custom ordering.

```
arr.iter().max_by(|a, b| a.abs().total_cmp(&b.abs()))
```

Finally, if this is a large project and you don't mind pulling in external dependencies, I recommend [`OrderedFloat`](https://docs.rs/ordered-float/latest/ordered_float/struct.OrderedFloat.html) for dealing with all of the awkwardness around NaN and floating point types. It provides an `Ord` instance for a float-like type which sorts NaN as part of the total ordering, rather than following the (frankly bizarre) IEEE rules for ordering floats. With that library, your maximum becomes

```
arr.iter().max_by_key(|x| OrderedFloat(x.abs())
```

Comment: Your suggestion 'arr.iter().max_by(|a, b| a.abs().total_cmp(b.abs()))' does not seem to work, i've included the error message in my edited question.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. It's just a bit of arguing with the borrow checker. It works after borrowing the result of `b.abs()`. See my edit.